# How to check if a series of timestamps are within a range of times (google sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, time, timestamp

I have a 200+ rows of timestamps.  I have two cells, say 4am and 10am.  I'm trying to write an If statement to see which rows time is between 4am and 10am, regardless of the day, month or year.

For example, B1 = 4am and B2 = 10am

A4 = "1/1/2020 3 am"

A5 = "1/2/2020 5 am"

A6 = "3/3/2020 11 am"

etc...

So only A5 would meet the conditions

Here's my pseudo-code:

IF(AND(A4>$B$1,A4<$B$2),"in between","NOT")

but column A has a timestamp format and I need to strip off the date part and just compare the times.  I'm trying to do this in google sheets.

Comment: after you have "in between" and "not", what do you plan on doing with that info? counting it? summing other values based on it? displaying whole rows based on it?    I ask because you're asking for an intermediary step, that is very possible, and I can show you, but it might end up being MORE complicated than if you asked for what the REAL end goal is.

Comment: Could you please provide a copy of the spreadsheet, free of sensitive information, clearly specifying the desired outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to compare the data after running it through [TIMEVALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267350?hl=en).

So instead of just referencing cell A4, you'd reference TIMEVALUE(A4), for example.

This will trim the date data from the string and you'll end up getting a number between 0 and 1. For example, TIMEVALUE("12:00 PM") would return 0.5.